# Files uploaded to hosting service don't appear on domain root

Tags: hosting, cpanel, file-manager

I recently paid for a domain and hosting services through two different vendors. I pointed the domain to the IP provided by the hosting service, uploaded my HTML through Cpanel to the public_html folder in file manager but the page does not load when I point my browser to the IP or my domain. Instead, I have to type in the IP or my domain and add /~MyUserName

Is there something I am doing wrong?  I can't access a higher level of folder in file manager than /~MyUserName.  Do I need to point my domain to the IP/~MyUserName?

Thanks in advance

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVKVO.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the file structure?

Comment: Link added (I can't post images yet).  It is the standard File Manager structure, I haven't changed anything, just uploaded my files to public_HTML.

Comment: have you checked if the dns setting is done? It may take some time for the dns settings to apply so i would recommend you do a dns lookup on your hostname and see if the IP you get is the same of your server.

Comment: Whois shows 5 IPs from Name-services.com, none of which were ever associated with my domain.  Does that mean it hasn't updated yet, or correctly?

Comment: Yes, i would wait a few hours (they say max 12h but i had free webhosts do it in 30m) and if it still does not work you should contact your webhost

Comment: It's been 12 hours now and still nothing.  The domain is pointing to the server (according to the error page), but not to the right files.

Comment: When you change A record (IP address pointer) for your domain, cPanel server start showing default cpanel page.When your domain is fully propagated and still you see default cpanel page then you can ask your web host to run command in SSH......./scripts/rebuildhttpdconf

Also clear your dns and browser cache.